# In Javascript how to find the object in an array that has the highest valued specific property while meeting some conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, oop, object

There is an array called `householdArray` populated with objects that have two properties: the first one is `isSelling`, the value of which is either `true`or `false`. The second one is `askingPrice`the value of which is a number. There is another object called `buyer` that has a `budget` property with a numerical value.

How do I find, out of all the objects that have `isSelling === true` in the `householdArray` which one has the highest `askingPrice`that is within `buyer`'s `budget`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filters and min max but i would do this job simply in one pass , in O(n) time by utilizing `Array.prototype.reduce()`. To encourage you using arrow functions I will show you first with the arrows then with conventional function implementation.

Please note that we use an object like `{isSelling: true, askingPrice: 0}` as initial value to the reduce operation.

```js
var buyer = {budget:1000},
household = [{  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 500},
             {  isSelling: false,
              askingPrice: 500},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 1000},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 790},
             {  isSelling: false,
              askingPrice: 1000},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 1200},
             {  isSelling: false,
              askingPrice: 690},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 890},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 1500},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 790},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 900},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 990},
             {  isSelling: false,
              askingPrice: 990},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 670}
            ],
   result = household.reduce((p,c) => c.isSelling === true          &&
                                      c.askingPrice <= buyer.budget &&
                                      c.askingPrice > p.askingPrice ? c : p,{isSelling: true, askingPrice: 0});
console.log(result);
```

And now with a conventional function implementation

```js
var buyer = {budget:1000},
household = [{  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 500},
             {  isSelling: false,
              askingPrice: 500},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 670},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 790},
             {  isSelling: false,
              askingPrice: 1000},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 1200},
             {  isSelling: false,
              askingPrice: 690},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 890},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 1500},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 790},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 900},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 990},
             {  isSelling: false,
              askingPrice: 990},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 1000}
            ],
   result = household.reduce(function(p,c){
                               return c.isSelling === true          &&
                                      c.askingPrice <= buyer.budget &&
                                      c.askingPrice > p.askingPrice ? c : p
                             },{isSelling: true, askingPrice: 0});
console.log(result);
```

And if you would like to get the index of the record that fits our condition you simply add the index argument to the callback of reduce and use an initial value of "0" as follows;

```js
var buyer = {budget:1000},
household = [{  isSelling: false,
              askingPrice: 1500},
             {  isSelling: false,
              askingPrice: 500},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 1000},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 670},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 790},
             {  isSelling: false,
              askingPrice: 1000},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 1200},
             {  isSelling: false,
              askingPrice: 690},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 890},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 1500},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 790},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 900},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 990},
             {  isSelling: false,
              askingPrice: 990}
            ],
   result = household.reduce(function(p,c,i,a){
                               return  a[p].isSelling === false        ||
                                       a[p].askingPrice > buyer.budget ||
                                       c.isSelling === true            &&
                                       c.askingPrice <= buyer.budget   &&
                                       c.askingPrice > a[p].askingPrice ? i : p;  
                             },0);
result = household[result].isSelling === true && household[result].askingPrice <= buyer.budget ? result : -1;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Good stuff. Although I was hoping for a solution that would return the index number of the "winning" item in the `household` array. In your example, the output i'd really like to get is `household[13]`. Is there a way to get that?

Comment: @neoflash Sure... let me give a modified version.

Comment: Great, this seems to work. Too bad I don't understand it. I read the reduce entries on MDN and w3schools but I can't seem too match what you did to the syntax they are using. I'm rather new to programming. Would you be kind enough to give me a plain english breakdown of your solution or maybe point me to some article that would explain the reduce method better. Thanks.

Comment: I think I found a problem with your code. It's not returning the index of the object that has the highest asking price, within budget and is selling === true, it is returning the object with the hightest index number that is selling === true and also within budget. 

For instance, If you were to take the object at index 13 and move it up to index 0, your code would now return 12 because that object has the highest index number while being is selling === true and within budget. I need code that would return 0, in that case.

Comment: @neoflash Hey you are right..! It was my oversight... I have just corrected the code. And later tonight, once i have time, i will explain step by step how the code works under my answer. Basically since we are using an "initial value" it works slightly different than the normal reduce workflow. Actually it's pretty well explained under MDN; just check the conditions when an initial value is present.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code seems to work great except for one thing. When no households fit the conditions, it returns 0. This is a problem because you would think that that means that the household at index 0 is the best option when in fact it could be too expensive or not even selling. Try changing the budget to 400 and you will see what I mean.

I will be using the `result` of your code in another function to tell the buyer to buy the house from `household[result]`. You can see how it would be a problem if `result` is 0 while index 0 does not in fact want to sell.

Comment: @neoflash Cool..! Yes true again :) Then it would be best to add a line to the bottom (as amended in the answer) to get things right. I believe this piece of code had done a lot on behalf of your debugging skills though.

Comment: Thanks to you I have a much better understanding of `.reduce`. And I have found another problem. I noticed that whenever index 0 was selling, even if the buyer's budget was below the asking price, `result`would return 0. Try changing the asking price for index 0 from 500 to 1500 and you will see what I mean. Now that I understand better understand how `reduce`works, I can understand why. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Here is the fix (I think), please add it to your answer if you think it makes sense.

    ...
    c.askingPrice <= buyer.budget &&
    c.askingPrice > a[p].askingPrice **||
    a[p].askingPrice > buyer.budget** ? i : p;
    }, 0);
    ...

Comment: @neoflash The problem arises from the need of the initial value index to point a valid item in the array. (we can not start with -1) Then we have to test all possible unfit conditions to eliminate this falsely selected item. Now that i have added one more line to our conditions chain in the answer. `a[p].isSelling === false ||`. So it should fix it. If all items have `isSelling` property as `false` or above the budget then we have the last line after reduce to eliminate that too. It's still O(n) but I guess reduce makes more sense when the desired item itself is filtered instead of it's index.

Comment: Yet i think it's been a great exercise for you to enter the functional part of JS. Reduce and map are two very important tools and since you now have grasped it's power you may start approaching many of the problems with the thought "Hey how about using reduce to solve it..?" Arrows are very easy and they are great when used in inline codes like this. The only thing you have to pay attention is the behavior of the `this` in the Arrows.

Comment: Can't believe I'm saying this but I think my fix was better. Your latest version is still buggy. Try changing index 0 to `true` and all the other ones to `false` except for index 4 (with the asking price of 790) and run it. It should give me 4 as a `result` yet gives me -1. My code which added `|| a[p].askingPrice > buyer.budget` had fixed that problem or did you see a problem with my solution?

Again, thanks for your help and your time. I learned so much these past few days.

Comment: @neoflash Yet you have discovered another hole. As per your solution; it's always best to go the way you are confident with. Your solution is great however i will once more fix the code for the sake of consistency. Again... resolving the index with reduce turned out to be a somewhat... let me say, not as straightforward and reasonable as resolving the object itself.

Comment: Hey thanks for re-electing my answer as accepted. Much more than that i have to say that i am very honored and pleased to be able to help you to progress you skills. Beyond any doubt i believe you have full capacity in programming. My last recommendation for you would be to have a look at JS Promises too. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find what you're looking for by filtering out those objects where isSelling === true and where the askingPrice is <= the buyer's budget. Then you can use Math.max.apply() on the array to find the object with the highest asking price within the budget. See below:

```
var buyer= {"budget": 700};

var householdArray = [{"isSelling": true, "askingPrice": 100}, {"isSelling": false, "askingPrice": 800}, {"isSelling": true, "askingPrice": 500}, {"isSelling": true, "askingPrice": 600}];

var qualifiedBudgets = householdArray.filter(x => x.isSelling && x.askingPrice <= buyer.budget);

//use map to get array of numbers representing the asking prices
var selectedArray = householdArray.find(f => f.askingPrice === Math.max.apply(null, qualifiedBudgets.map(x => x.askingPrice)));

//value should be the array with asking price of 600
console.log(selectedArray);
```

You can also chain it together too like:

```
var selectedArray= householdArray.find(f => f.askingPrice === Math.max.apply(null, householdArray.filter(x => x.isSelling && x.askingPrice <= buyer.budget).map(x => x.askingPrice)));
```

Comment: I'm sorry to ask but I am not familiar with arrow function syntax and the environment I'm using does not support ES6, could you show me what it would look like with traditional function syntax. Thank you.

Comment: This is javascript, no ES6 should be needed. You're performing the filter function on the array. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter for an example on using the filter method. Works the same with .find.

Answer (score 0):

This is called filtering and sorting.

```js
var buyer = {budget:1000};
var household = [{  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 500},
             {  isSelling: false,
              askingPrice: 500},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 1000},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 790},
             {  isSelling: false,
              askingPrice: 1000},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 1200},
             {  isSelling: false,
              askingPrice: 690},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 890},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 1500},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 790},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 900},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 990},
             {  isSelling: false,
              askingPrice: 990},
             {  isSelling: true,
              askingPrice: 670}
            ];

function budgetFilter(obj) {
  if (obj.isSelling === true && obj.askingPrice <= buyer.budget) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

var result = household.filter(budgetFilter);
result.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a.askingPrice < b.askingPrice) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.askingPrice > b.askingPrice) {
    return -1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
});

console.log('Filtered Array\n', result[0]); 
//console.log('Filtered Array\n', result);  show sorted array
```